# Is there any jquery sort plugin like drupal taxonomy terms

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drupal, jquery-plugins

I like the feature in sorting in drupal's taxonomy like this:
http://drupal.org/project/nodeorder
or if you already have experience editing taxonomy in drupal 7.

It provides a tree/directory like structure sorting...

I've been trying 2d sorts on jquery ui and the nested sortable plugin:
 http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/

But i'm b!tch!n' on the features of the sort in drupal, because it's clean and friendly in table like format.

Can anybody provide me a better alternative? I've been searching through drupal repos and no luck

Answer (score 0):

Table sorting with JQuery UI:

http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/tzYbU/

You can apply your own CSS to create whatever look & feel you want. Note that this does not support parent child relationships.

Something that does support parent-child relationships is a JQuery 'treeTable' plugin at: https://github.com/ludo/jquery-treetable

Here is a jsFiddle that implements the treeTable plugin:
http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Tbd38/10/

With fairly simple code:

```
    $(document).ready(function()  {
        $("#dragndrop").treeTable({
              expandable: false
        });

        // Drag & Drop Code
        $("#dragndrop .entry").draggable({
          helper: "clone",
          opacity: .75,
          refreshPositions: true, // Performance?
          revert: "invalid",
          revertDuration: 300,
          scroll: true
         }
        );

        $("#dragndrop .entry").each(function() {
          $($(this).parents("tr")[0]).droppable({
            drop: function(e, ui) {
              $($(ui.draggable).parents("tr")[0]).appendBranchTo(this);
              setNewParent($($(ui.draggable).parents("tr")[0]).attr("id"), $(this).attr("id"));
            },
            hoverClass: "accept",
            over: function(e, ui) {
              if(this.id != $(ui.draggable.parents("tr")[0]).id && !$(this).is(".expanded")) {
                $(this).expand();
              }
            }
          });
        });

        function setNewParent(child, parent)
        {
            // do ajax call here
            //alert(child);
            //alert(parent);
        }
    });
```

The main drawbacks with this plugin:

- You cannot reorder nodes that are at the same level.
- You cannot move a node right up to the very top level.

Someone who has the time may be able to fork the plugin and add these features to it.

Comment: Thank you for this but I also wanted it to have that parent-child relationship in sorting, in this, you may also want to drag-sort left or right to set what that row's parent may be. It may be done by adding a class perhaps upon drag to set that row be a child or a parent to another row.

I know it may be done using long and brute code (since I'm much a javascript user not a developer), and looking for a jquery plugin would really fit for this

Comment: @user1076813 updated with a `treeTable` plugin, but couldn't find anything else.